# C# Access value from serialized json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I have a simple serialized json array

```
string json = "[{\"id\":100,\"UserId\":99},{\"id\":101,\"UserId\":98}]";
var data = (List<Model>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json , typeof(List<Model>));
```

my model to deserialize:

```
public class Model 
{ 
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to retrieve data from each Index[?] and print it to Console ?

Comment: @devopsEMK I know how to deserialize . it works successfully but I having issue fetching data from index as i cant compare with data.length in a for loop.

Comment: What's the problem with using `data[n]` and `data.Count`, exactly? Also you can get rid of the cast by using `var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string json = "[{\"id\":100,\"UserId\":99},{\"id\":101,\"UserId\":98}]";
        var objects = JArray.Parse(json);
        var firstIndexValue = objects[0];
        Console.WriteLine(firstIndexValue);

        foreach (var index in objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }
for (int index = 0; index < objects.Count; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(objects[index]);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help . But what if i don't know the index value instead i want to print each index value one by one ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var item in data) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.UserId);
}
```